# What‘s does new (getClass()) mean?

Tags: javascript, frontend

```
function getClass(name) {
   switch (name) {
      case 'string': return String;
      case 'array': return Array;
      default: return Object;
   }
}
obj = new (getClass());
```

So could anyone pls explain these codes, I understand new but what is new()?

Comment: The parentheses don't do anything, they're just for grouping things. It seems to be the programmer's personal style or overcautiousness (there are unnecessary parentheses in the switch statement too.)

Comment: @JJJ Wrong. The parentheses are necessary to ensure that `getClass` is called with no parameter, and then `new` is invoked on the result, such as `String`. Without the parentheses, it would invoke the `getClass` function itself as a constructor.

Comment: @torazaburo, would you like to answer the question? it would works with `obj = new getClass()();` as well, which is more obvious than the other style.

Comment: @NinaScholz If I am not mistaken, and haven't tested it, `new getClass()()` would call the `getClass` constructor with no parameters, then try to invoke the resulting instance, which would most likely result in an error of trying to invoke a non-function.

Comment: @torazaburo, the [precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) is saying, new goes first, the function, but with testing the part, the result is first function then new.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't think this is a dup and it should be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 obj = new (getClass());
```

This means:

1. Call the `getClass` function with no arguments (`getClass()`). That returns either `String`, or `Array`, or `Object`, the latter in this case.
2. Call `new` on the return value from `getClass()`. In that case, that equates to `new Object`, which creates a new object.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
object = new getClass()(); // object = new (getClass());
```

which explain better whats happen. It calls the function `getClass` and returns an object for a new instance.

```js
function getClass(name) {
    switch (name) {
        case 'string': return String;
        case 'array': return Array;
        default: return Object;
    }
}

var typeObject = new getClass()(),
    typeArray = new getClass('array')(),
    typeString = new getClass('string')();

[typeObject, typeArray, typeString].forEach(function (o) {
    console.log(typeof o);
    if (typeof o === 'object') {
        console.log('hasOwnProperty' in o);
        console.log('splice' in o);
    }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```